# adding custom marker to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying for some time now to get a custom marker to a google maps frame. Both custom and standard markers won't show.

I am using the following code:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

var map;


function init() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.231245, 6.078348),
        zoom: 10,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
        },
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        streetViewControl: true,
        draggable : true,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: true,
        },

}    

 var image = 'http://aandegrens.appartdev.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Google_Maps.png';
 var myLatLng = {lat: 51.231245, lng: 6.078348};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
 title: 'Hello World',
    icon: image
  });
  

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions)};
```

The map itself shows up fine and works all good, only the marker doesn't show.

Comment: Your icon is not publicly available: http://aandegrens.appartdev.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Google_Maps.png (it is asking for a password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `map: map` on the marker before the map has been created. Just move `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);` before `var image = ...` and it should work.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uj13t71y/

Comment: Here is a fiddle with it working. There was an authorization issue with your custom image. https://jsfiddle.net/uj13t71y/

Comment: Ah, I see. Works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Uhm I created by my self the simple custom marker
You can check the result by clicking into the map
It will create new marker with nice WIFI effect like this

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM43e.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jejmg.png)

```js
function CustomMarker(latlng, map, args) {
 this.latlng = latlng; 
 this.args = args; 
 this.setMap(map); 
}

CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
var cur_node;
CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
 
 var self = this;
 
 var div = this.div;
 
 if (!div) {
 
  div = this.div = document.createElement('div');
  
  div.className = 'cd-single-point';
  div.innerHTML = '<a class="cd-img-replace" title="MN1"></a>';
  
  if (typeof(self.args.marker_id) !== 'undefined') {
   div.dataset.marker_id = self.args.marker_id;
  }
  var cur = this.getPosition();
  var me  = this;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "contextmenu", function(event) {
   //alert('You clicked on a custom marker!');   
   //google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
   cur_node= cur;
   me.remove();
   
  });
  
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
 }
 
 var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.getPosition());
 
 if (point) {
  div.style.left = (point.x-7 ) + 'px';
  div.style.top = (point.y-7) + 'px';
 }
};

CustomMarker.prototype.remove = function() {
 if (this.div) {
  this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
  this.div = null;
 } 
};

CustomMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {
 return this.latlng; 
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<title>Google Maps API</title>

<style type="text/css">

#map {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 1000px;
}

 .cd-single-point {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.cd-single-point>a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #0079ff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.cd-single-point::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
}
 
@keyframes cd-pulse
{
0%  {box-shadow:0 0 0 0 #0079ff}
100%{box-shadow:0 0 0 20px rgba(255,150,44,0)}
}


</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CustomGoogleMapMarker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var cen;
function initialize() {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'Ha noi, Vietnam'}, function(results, status) {
    cen = results[0].geometry.location;
    
   try{
   var myStyles =[
   
       {
         featureType: "administrative",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "poi",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "water",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "road",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       }
     
];
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: cen,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       streetViewControl: false, styles: myStyles 
   
    }); 
    }catch(e){alert(e)}
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: cen,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
    /*
var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: cen,
            radius: 2
          });*/
    
    map.addListener('click', function(e) {
     var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path: [cen, e.latLng],
       geodesic: true,
       strokeColor: 'blue',
       strokeOpacity: 0.6,
       strokeWeight: 1,
       map: map
     });
     overlay = new CustomMarker(
      e.latLng, 
      map,
      {
       marker_id: '123'
      }
     );
    });
    
    map.addListener('rightclick', function(e) {
    if(cur_node) {
     var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path: [cur_node, e.latLng],
       geodesic: true,
       strokeColor: 'blue',
       strokeOpacity: 0.6,
       strokeWeight: 1,
       map: map
     });
     overlay = new CustomMarker(
      e.latLng, 
      map,
      {
       marker_id: '123'
      }
     );
    }
    });
  });
 

 
 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

</head>
<body>

 <div id="map">
 </div>
Hope it helps!
</body>
</html>
```